# RenderBody in ASP.Net MVC is in the wrong order for one page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-table

Here is my situation:
I am doing an ASP.Net MVC Web application and one of the page is not behaving normally.

Usually this is what it renders (visually):
Navbar (I'm using Bootstrap),
H1 Title of the page,
Body of the page,
Footer

But I have one page that behaves like this:
Navbar,
H1 Title of the page,
Footer,
Body of the page.

I tried to set a "Hello world" after my table (in the code) and this hello is at it's rightful place (between the h1 title and the footer).

The only difference with other pages is that this one is a table that is generated with a list of models.  It is generated using the usual

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
Display each property of the item
<tr>
}
```

The model (when debugging) is not empty.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your view code, please. From one working page and the mentioned above.
Where are your <table>-tags?

Comment: Try an HTML validator (search google) online versions available.  Do a "view source" and paste your html and see if there any tags missing or mismatched.

Comment: @JimKennelly Thank you, simple error, forgot to close a tag. I never expected the console/debug tools to not flag such an error... Next time I'll know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was simple enough, it failed the html validation, an end tag was missing. To fix it, simply use an online HTML validator.